# WPF TextBlock binding deactivate & detach

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have started seeing an unusual issue with some of the binding on my textblocks:

**XAML**

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding PartCount,FallbackValue=1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" Foreground="Black" Margin="-3"/>
```

I know for sure that my binding path resolution is correct because if I change this block to a label with content instead of text then it works just fine.

I have the diagnostic logger enabled for the binding and I can see it initialise correctly and set the initial value from its source:

**DEBUG LOG**

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=40999308):
> Resolving source  (last chance) System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 :
> BindingExpression (hash=40999308): Found data context element:
> TextBlock (hash=5477191) (OK) System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 :
> BindingExpression (hash=40999308): Activate with root item LoadStack
> (hash=22395825) System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression
> (hash=40999308):   At level 0 using cached accessor for
> LoadStack.PartCount: RuntimePropertyInfo(PartCount)
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=40999308):
> Replace item at level 0 with LoadStack (hash=22395825), using accessor
> RuntimePropertyInfo(PartCount) System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 :
> BindingExpression (hash=40999308): GetValue at level 0 from LoadStack
> (hash=22395825) using RuntimePropertyInfo(PartCount): 'Infinity'
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=40999308):
> TransferValue - got raw value 'Infinity' System.Windows.Data Warning:
> 84 : BindingExpression (hash=40999308): TransferValue - implicit
> converter produced '∞' System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 :
> BindingExpression (hash=40999308): TransferValue - using final value
> '∞'

But then, when I navigate to the window that shows this text box I get this:

**DEBUG LOG**

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 79 : BindingExpression (hash=40999308):
> Deactivate System.Windows.Data Warning: 103 : BindingExpression
> (hash=40999308): Replace item at level 0 with {NullDataItem}
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 63 : BindingExpression (hash=40999308):
> Detach

So after this point the visual element does not update, but I do still get information in the log when the source changes like so:

**DEBUG LOG**

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=53188122):
> Got PropertyChanged event from LoadStack (hash=22395825)
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=53188122):
> GetValue at level 0 from LoadStack (hash=22395825) using
> RuntimePropertyInfo(PartCount): '50' System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 :
> BindingExpression (hash=53188122): TransferValue - got raw value '50'
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=53188122):
> TransferValue - implicit converter produced '50' System.Windows.Data
> Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=53188122): TransferValue - using
> final value '50'

So something is causing that "deactivate" & "detach" which means that it no longer updates the view. I have checked that the data context is consistent, which it is.

Is there anything that can cause the binding to respond in this way?

Comment: Remove this , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged and never use it again until you understand what it does.

Comment: Show us your viewmodel. Does it implement inotifypropertychanged?  What's your property look like. What exactly is it's initial value? What happens if you remove your fallbackvalue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detachment behavior usually occurs when a value is set outside of the data binding.

The way to go is to check if you're setting TextBlock.Text somewhere else (e.g. in the code behind or in your XAML).

Another possibility is that your viewmodel instance gets replaced by another one.

Comment: Thanks very much! This directed us to some rudimentary translation software we'd put in which was setting the value externally, but it was so distant from the code being debugged that it hadn't crossed our mind.